# Enviar el signo de multiplicación por parametro en bash

Tags: linux, bash

Buenas estoy tratando de realizar una calculadora en la consola bash, donde se le envió 3 parámetros. El primer parámetro es un numero igual que el segundo, pero en el tercer parámetro le envió la operación a realizar, puede ser (+, -, /, %, *), todos los signos funcionan bien, menos el signo de multiplicar.
Mi pregunta es como logro enviar este signo como parámetro, ya que no me lo toma como tal.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

if [ $3 = 'suma' -o $3 = '+' ]
  then echo 'la suma de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 + $2))
elif [ $3 = 'resta' -o $3 = '-' ]
  then echo 'la resta de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 - $2))
elif [ $3 = 'multiplicacion' -o $3 = '*' ]
  then echo 'la multiplicacion de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1*$2))
elif [ $3 = 'division' -o $3 = '/' ]
  then echo 'la division de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 / $2))
elif [ $3 = 'modulo' -o $3 = '%' ]
  then echo 'la modulo de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 % $2))
else 
  echo "no es una operacion valida"
fi
```

adjunto imagen de la salidas

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: escápale! `\*` el bash reemplaza * por "todo lo q encuentra" es lo q hace funcionar el `ls *.algo` en tu caso encontro el mismo archivo `calculadora.sh`

Comment: YA lo escape y ni asi funciona!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El escapeao al llamar el script es para que el bash actual no expanda el * a los nombres de todos los archivos que encuentra.

```
$ ./test.bash 10 20 \*
```

También sirve pasarlo en quotes

```
$ ./test.bash 10 20 '*'
```

Sin embargo, dentro del script bash va expandir el `\*` ó `'*'` porque ahora es un `*`

Para evitar esas expansiones dentro del script, podes llamar al script usando bash con la opción `-f`

```
$ bash -f ./test.bash 10 20 '*'
```

O en el script decir que querés esa opción para el script

```
#!/bin/bash -f
echo 'sin expansión'
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
#...
```

O dentro del script setear y des(?)setear la opción `-f`, por si luego necesitas expandir cosa, algo así:

```
#!/bin/bash
#sin expansion
set -f
echo 'sin expansión'
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3

if [ $3 = 'suma' -o $3 = '+' ]
  then echo 'la suma de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 + $2))
elif [ $3 = 'resta' -o $3 = '-' ]
  then echo 'la resta de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 - $2))
elif [ $3 = 'multiplicacion' -o $3 = '*' ]
  then echo 'la multiplicacion de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1*$2))
elif [ $3 = 'division' -o $3 = '/' ]
  then echo 'la division de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 / $2))
elif [ $3 = 'modulo' -o $3 = '%' ]
  then echo 'la modulo de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 % $2))
else
  echo "no es una operacion valida"
fi
#con expansion ( habilitamos luego de los ifs para que no proteste )
set +f
echo 'con expansión'
echo $1
echo $2
echo $3
```

resultado

```
$ ./test.bash 10 20 '*'
sin expansión
10
20
*
la multiplicacion de  10 y 20 es:  200
con expansión
10
20
test.bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Siento que lo más prudente y estandar sería encerrar todo entre comillas y evitar jugar con variables de la shell.

Sin embargo, puedes deshabilitar la opción del glob:

```
$ set -o noglob
```

Y ya luego llamar a tu script con todo entrecomillado:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

operacion="$3"

echo "$1"
echo "$2"
echo "$3"

if [ "$operacion" = 'suma' -o "$operacion" = '+' ]; then
    echo 'la suma de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 + $2))
elif [ "$operacion"3 = 'resta' -o "$operacion" = '-' ]; then
    echo 'la resta de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 - $2))
elif [ "$operacion" = 'multiplicacion' -o "$operacion" = '*' ]; then
    echo 'la multiplicacion de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1*$2))
elif [ "$operacion" = 'division' -o "$operacion" = '/' ];
    then echo 'la division de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 / $2))
elif [ "$operacion" = 'modulo' -o "$operacion" = '%' ]; then
    echo 'la modulo de ' $1 'y '$2 'es: ' $(($1 % $2))
else
    echo "no es una operacion valida"
fi
```

Y con esa opción de `noglob`, ya podías hacer esto:

```
./calculadora.sh 4 4 *
```

Y luego habilitarla de nuevo con `shopt +o noglob`.